# There is a function with this condition...

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples

Show that there is a function $f : P(\Bbb{N} ) \to \Bbb{N}$ ,(  $P(\Bbb{N})$ is power set) with this condition that for $A \in P(\Bbb{N})-  \{\emptyset \}$ , $f(A) \in A$ , is there function with this condition and  $\Bbb{Q} , \Bbb{Z} ,\Bbb{R} $.

Comment: This is the axiom of choice.

Comment: Wow, this question needs some serious rephrasing.

Comment: for $\mathbb{N}$, $f(A)=\min(A)$ will do it

Comment: Yes, we can, or use maximum.

Comment: @amirbahadory no you can't because $\max(\mathbb{N})=\infty$ is not in $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Yes, for $ \Bbb{Z}  $ is there ?

Comment: for $\mathbb{Z}$, let $g: P(\mathbb{N})-\{\emptyset\} \to P(\mathbb{N})$ s.t. $g(A)=\{x \in A / \forall y \in A, |y| \ge |x|\}$. Take $f(A)=\max(g(A))$

Comment: Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, let $u : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Q}$ be bijective, take $f(A) =u( \min(u^{-1}(A)))$

Comment: @amirbahadory note that the proof I gave for $\mathbb{Q}$ works for  $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @Nitrogen It is not. You probably meant "this is a result of the axiom of choice" (although there's no need for choice for some of the sets OP has shown).